# Change in the location of data source and column header ,what changes do I have to do in my source dataset copy activity pipeline i

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

For my pie chart visual in power bi,there is some change in data source location and column header.
How to approach this problem if I have to two separate pipelines one is getting data activity and the other is copy data activity in my adf pipeline.Do I have to create new source dataset in source of copy activity?please let me know

I have to make adjustments in my adf pipeline

Answer (score 0):

If your source is a power BI rest dataset, you can make the changes in the existing dataset like below. Go to **Dataset-> edit**-> edit the changes in the linked service like Base URL as per your requirement.

Sample Power BI REST dataset:

[image]

This is same for any dataset, you can edit the linked service and also change the file location if it's a file system dataset or Storage account dataset as per your requirement.